# How to download cacti 0.9 files from its web directory?

Tags: file-download

How to download cacti 0.9 (PHP) files from its web directory?

I need cacti version 0.9 to work on it but i don't know how can i download all of its files at once from below directory: http://svn.cacti.net/viewvc/cacti/archive/archive-0.9/

Is there anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Use This app for windows:
http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Or related Q:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341134/command-line-svn-for-windows

And See this page for Useful SVN Commands:

http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands

Detailed:

First of all, download and Install Sliksvn from here:

sliksvn.com/en/download

Then, browse to bin directory with cmd.exe and open svn.exe

Finally, write below command to download cacti into a directory named cacti in bin folder:

svn checkout svn://svn.cacti.net/cacti